# Parsing text inside brackets using regexp

Tags: java, regex, wiki

I have a text in which I can not put html tags, to make links I would use syntax like wiki [go to the app](http://foo.com), I would like to extract text using regular expressions and transform the text into html. I tried using the regular expression \[.\) But it doesn't seems to work.

```
Pattern wikiLink = Pattern.compile("\\[.\\)");
Matcher mURL = wikiLink.matcher(content);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (mURL.find()) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
\[.*?\]\(http://.*?\)
```

this regular expression will find all text of the form

```
[text](http://url)
```

Comment: I founded the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553222/regex-pattern-to-return-text-from-within-brackets) thanks a lot to stackoverflow

Comment: The regex in the link you provide will find all text between *any* brackets. Even if they appear in normal text. And that is not what you requested.

Try it out for on [a regex tester](http://regexpal.com/) for the text
*blah (blah) blah*